# DataTables internationalization with local language file in Shiny

Tags: jquery, r, shiny, dt

I want to translate my datatable in shiny with the help of the provided internationalization file but instead of linking to the website, I need to link  the file on my computer (VM with no internet connection)
How can I acheive that ?

I tried to follow the step here https://rstudio.github.io/DT/004-i18n.html but instead of using "http://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.19/i18n/French.json", i tried with "file:///www/French.json" with no succes

Here my code

```
library(DT)

ui <- basicPage(
  DT::dataTableOutput("mytable")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable(
    mtcars,
  options = list(
    language = list(url = "file:///www/French.json")
  ))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Edit: I tried this with no luck

```
language = list({
  "language": {
    "sProcessing": "Traitement en cours ...",
    "sLengthMenu": "Afficher _MENU_ lignes",
    "sZeroRecords": "Aucun résultat trouvé",
    "sEmptyTable": "Aucune donnée disponible",
    "sInfo": "Lignes _START_ à _END_ sur _TOTAL_",
    "sInfoEmpty": "Aucune ligne affichée",
    "sInfoFiltered": "(Filtrer un maximum de_MAX_)",
    "sInfoPostFix": "",
    "sSearch": "Chercher:",
    "sUrl": "",
    "sInfoThousands": ",",
    "sLoadingRecords": "Chargement...",
    "oPaginate": {
      "sFirst": "Premier", "sLast": "Dernier", "sNext": "Suivant", "sPrevious": "Précédent"
    },
    "oAria": {
      "sSortAscending": ": Trier par ordre croissant", "sSortDescending": ": Trier par ordre décroissant"
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: In my Shiny apps, I simply have the content of the localization file in my R script. Alternatively, you could load the file separately using a package like `jsonlite`. If you have a list-object called `language_FR` in your R environment, you can simply substitute `language = language_FR` in your `renderDataTable` call.

Comment: @A.Stam I can't figure how to put the content dirently, I tried with language = "{"sProcessing": "Traitement en cours", [...] }" without luck, can you post your solution ? Thanks

Comment: Anything in the `www` directory can be reached without including the `www`.

Comment: @Serk I define it like any other list object: `language_NL <- list(sProcessing = "Bezig...", ...)` etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In R, you can use a `list` directly :

```
fr <- list(
  sProcessing = "Traitement en cours...", sSearch = "Rechercher&nbsp;:", 
  sLengthMenu = "Afficher _MENU_ &eacute;l&eacute;ments", 
  sInfo = "Affichage de l'&eacute;l&eacute;ment _START_ &agrave; _END_ sur _TOTAL_ &eacute;l&eacute;ments", 
  sInfoEmpty = "Affichage de l'&eacute;l&eacute;ment 0 &agrave; 0 sur 0 &eacute;l&eacute;ment", 
  sInfoFiltered = "(filtr&eacute; de _MAX_ &eacute;l&eacute;ments au total)", 
  sInfoPostFix = "", sLoadingRecords = "Chargement en cours...", 
  sZeroRecords = "Aucun &eacute;l&eacute;ment &agrave; afficher", 
  sEmptyTable = "Aucune donn&eacute;e disponible dans le tableau", 
  oPaginate = list(
    sFirst = "Premier", sPrevious = "Pr&eacute;c&eacute;dent", 
    sNext = "Suivant", sLast = "Dernier"
  ), 
  oAria = list(
    sSortAscending = ": activer pour trier la colonne par ordre croissant", 
    sSortDescending = ": activer pour trier la colonne par ordre d&eacute;croissant"
  )
)

library(DT)
library(shiny)

ui <- basicPage(
  DT::DTOutput("mytable")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$mytable = DT::renderDT({
    mtcars
  },
  options = list(
    language = fr
  ))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

If you want to use the JSON provided [here](http://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.19/i18n/French.json), download it into your `www` folder and use :

```
language = list(url = "French.json") # without www/
```

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick ! I forgot to modify the JSON when using it inline